# Unique characters generated from DateFormat.format(...)

Tags: android

I create a URL using a given date as a parameter.

This date is created thusly:

```
final String from = DateFormat.format("dd.MM.yyyy", date).toString();
```

This string is added to a URL:

```
+ "&from=" + from
```

Errors started appearing in my Crashlytics reporter. To debug, I set it to report the URLs that were being sent.

How is it that the URL being generated can look like this: `&from=٢٩.٠٦.٢٠١٦`?

Comment: I don't know yet. I sent them an E-mail to ask.

Comment: it was my answer to your *How is it that the URL being generated can look like this*. Since you are not providing a specific locale, the default's one is probably being used.

Comment: your date format and the formatting is correct. the url creation process needs to be taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blackbelt has noted, the date is formatted as such because of the Locale on the user's phone.

You could simply convert the date to the format you want specifying English locale.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String from = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the most obvious answer. I googled the individual terms and it appears to be Arabic. Google even turns RTL when searching for "٢٠١٦" (2016). You solution will likely solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to your phone's default `Locale`.

Use this to get the date in correct format :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

String from = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Read more about `SimpleDateFormat` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)).